# Reference over array into array of reference

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

I have an array `std::array<T, N> arr` for some `T`, `N` and I'd like to get an array of reference over `arr`'s elements like so `std::array<std::reference_wrapper<T>, N> arr_ref`.

But as a reference needs to be set at its initialization, I did not work out a solution.
Therefore I would like to do something like that:

```cpp
std::array<std::reference_wrapper<T>, N> ref{}
for (std::size_t i{0}; i < N; ++i)
  ref[i] = arr[i];
```

But at compile-time and at the initialization of `ref`.

I thought of using some variadic template magic to convert my initial array to a parameter pack and then take a reference to each element but I am not sure this is possible.

My last option would be an array of raw ptrs or of `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`.

Comment: Why do you need references to the individually elements, instead of having a reference to the actual array (as in `auto& ref = arr;`)? What is the actual and underlying problem your individual references is supposed to solve?

Comment: Feels like you are trying to create iterators, which already exist for arrays.

Comment: And there's also `std::span`

Comment: I have a generic custom Container<T> that internaly uses std::array<T, ...> and I would like to create a view over one with the same interface, e.g. create a Container<T&> ;
Maybe this is a bad architecture

Comment: Then [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (already mentioned, with [Boost span](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/span.html) as an alternative) might be useful. Or [the ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) (or [the range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) the standard ranges is based on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename x_Item, ::std::size_t x_count, ::std::size_t... x_index___>
auto wrap_impl(::std::array<x_Item, x_count> & items, ::std::index_sequence<x_index___...>)
{
    return ::std::array<::std::reference_wrapper<x_Item>, x_count>{items[x_index___]...};
}

template<typename x_Item, ::std::size_t x_count>
auto wrap(::std::array<x_Item, x_count> & items)
{
    return wrap_impl(items, ::std::make_index_sequence<x_count>{});
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    ::std::array items{1, 2, 3};
    auto wrapped_items{wrap(items)};
    for (auto & wrapped_item: wrapped_items)
    {
        ::std::cout << wrapped_item.get() << ::std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzBqkAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmscHI3lgA1CaxbvXETACee9gmGgCCaxtbmLv7VF4MDuliZxfXZusvdw9uXkctEIp1i5yuN1%2BXh2ezcyEG6CwVA%2BEKuBEwLESBnRsIIx0SjFY91UAH0AJLolikbYgEAI2mpABemBJBG2pLQzwI1IZBHQDLwzNZADpReyScEsKSSSSUZcmIDUNsAO5HRISzG0CC8/kgQ4nWGkikY6kchaCM67MwANm2hAxCh5dL5tMlmFJSgAjl5GMtDRKGFKZSTRcKzjNPiYAOxWK7bePbYiYAiLBg0526/Wgtw62lJqjRX0s1VMRIE4j%2B40sM6mkmci1g6MWe0sBQmACsFlJbulsvbABFQ9H%2B3tY9coyPUZdKVimDj9niCcw2OKq076XTBSy2WauXKFUQVWrtRnaVnK5Ta/WCJbzLaWwoIxCY58E4nk6mj6WNViIA/1y6IAsEwADWLI9iSXo%2Bi8mD%2BteHwvhOEaxGOw6RhC3y3NC9ywk4gxJqwcqfMEbLAcEEBPuOY5vrmerEEcxx2pSbYxq02xmNSsRoShr4JgeSolmWmDoBKzFNoJf7MRGE6jrx8b8MQ2wQPxVq2oJBIiS2IBfkJmlSXJuwvnGb4JrRnJsrCsI6RpokYsKwDJhR/xWbRri0LJxnxmhnnvimxBphoHnjpOlwcHMtCcO2vB%2BBwWikKgnBuNY1jbAoCxLDh3w8KQBCaGFcwgSA7YJBFHCSNFeXxZwvAKCACS5bFYWkHAsAwIgKCoJidDROQlBoF19AxMAXBmK0NC0OixC1RAESVREwT1McnDZf1bCCAA8gwtBLY1pBYMBRjiLt%2BBJq8ABumC1bt7qYMggIrNlJGVJVwIREcxDHB4WCVQQxB4Cwy1NVQBjAAoABqeCYMq61LoDMiCCIYjsFI8PyEoaiVborQGEYKDJZY%2Bh4BEtWQHMqCJNUV0ALRUwiez9qYljWGYGjbFTADqYi0Gz7Pur9TA8xphiOMgNWVLd1QuIGIwtKQgTBL0JT9K0uRpAIMs5CkasMJMfQxGM4uvAInTDJ4zQDIb1Qm90CtTMrthDI0ZujA7Ey23rszzIsyx6L9mAPU1pVRaQMVxQlHCqAAHNaVPWpI2zAMgyDbCNwpcEpSVMwT2y4IQJBWrEbEeAN0QF1wMy8A1WgzAVRUlZw5WkADxUh5V4c1XVOV5XMLXtQsBCJICvUQP1iTdcQoREpwUcx3HCdJynZhp7wwl539/JjbIiPiCj/CCIoKjqLtWOkIJgPhZFFW7eH62AoPbKoFQ7LR7H8eJ8nqfpxAxdj4NZcV13RqNdSAIEwEwLAMQKL6AbrwZuCRQ68HbrYTuVd8qkEKi3UqsQr5h2qoA6uF8OBmBwYgvBqDgEXSmukEAkggA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: Ow,  I did not think of using an index_sequence! Thanks